# Retagging questions with the [pseudo-selector] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

In CSS, there is a fundamental difference between `:pseudo-classes` and `::pseudo-elements`. The term "pseudo-selector" doesn't exist in any official W3C specification, and is completely ambiguous between the two. (I'm aware that [the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) introduces the double-colon notation for pseudo-elements to resolve the ambiguity between the two, but the spec states that it isn't enforced for CSS1 and 2 pseudo-elements, and we have to stick with single colons [for a reason](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/after-v-after-what-is-double-colon-notation/).)

I know there are some libraries and implementations out there that call such selectors of their own "pseudo-selectors", but my question here is specific to questions about CSS (and quite possibly jQuery, whose selector engine Sizzle is based heavily on CSS selectors anyway, even though it's a library in itself).

May I retag and edit questions with the [pseudo-selector](/questions/tagged/pseudo-selector) tag? The [pseudo-class](/questions/tagged/pseudo-class) and [pseudo-element](/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) tags already exist anyway. I realize this is another one of those things that I'm really picky about, but as I mentioned there's an important fundamental difference between the two, and there is almost no scenario that could cover both entities categorically, so I believe that it's good to clarify this distinction.

Or is there such a scenario...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found an example of when using the term "pseudo-selector" can cause confusion: [Get :first-letter of :hover element with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528583/get-first-letter-of-hover-element-with-css) (read the question's comments)

Since nobody's objected via comments, answers or even downvotes, I'll go on ahead and retag.

Comment: ... aaaaand I'm done.